# Manejar números grandes

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de manejar cerca de 14 número de un ID (que debe ser numérico) para hacer un tipo de ordenamiento de mayor a menor. También imprimirlos, etc.
Sin embargo, con un double, primero que todo me imprime unos ceros demás si le pongo un fixed o no me los imprime completos, me sale algo como: 1.23457e+018

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double n = 1234567891011121314;
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor explicate mejor

Comment: Necesito todos los números en pantalla. O que si haga algún tipo de calculo, sean con los 14 números, no con basura: porque me añade números demás.

Comment: La forma en que esta redactada tu pregunta hace que sea difícil entender lo que quieres, revisa la redacción h arregla tu pregunta

Comment: Puedes trabajar con un arreglo donde cada elemento de este sea un digito del número, de esta forma el número puede ser tan grande como desees

Comment: Porque queres manejar algo que claramente no es un numero, como numero? un id de 14 posiciones por mas que sean numeros, no son numeros.. es una cadena, se ordena de la misma forma que una cadena, se rellena con 0 a la izquierda de ser necesario, y se imprime bonito sin hacer demasiado... Los numeros se usan para sumar, restar y hacer operaciones.. Esto es como querer meter un numero de telefono en una variable numerica...

Comment: Igual, si sale asi "1.23457e+018" por pantalla, solamente quiere decir que tenes que usar un formateador para mostrarlo (aclarar como se va a mostrar ;), algun experto lo sabra mejor que yo)

Comment: Revisa la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) para el formato

Comment: Tal como comenta @gbianchi, lo que debes hacer es manejar el valor como una cadena. El ordenamiento sobre valores de cadena se hace lexicográficamente, por lo cual no necesitas un número. Por ejemplo, un ordenamiento lexicográfico ascendete sobre las cadenas "123" y "124", te dará como resultado que primero va "123" y después "124". Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Los números en coma flotante de doble precisión (`double`) no pueden almacenar todos los números enteros de su rango<sup>1</sup>, en su lugar guarda aproximaciones y por ese motivo (entre otros) usa la notación científica para mostrar el número. Si necesitas números enteros grandes deberás usar un tipo entero como `long long`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long n = 1234567891011121314;
    std::cout << n << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDoMgEIDh2XuKSxxshyYeaq1K@yRdCBJDgodBmJo@OyVdvuX/9XHctFO85Vxb1i6tBqX1ZwxG7S8AyxF3ZflyhQ9UzvOGfxifSKLrh/v4mKglIkEd9QtUZ1znWfsUUcqyFZo3NyUEE1NgbBf45ixAwAA/)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>± 4.940.656.458.412 × 10<sup>-324</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mostrar todos los números simplemente almacénalos en un array de n elementos siendo n la cantidad de dígitos que tiene el entero. Que yo sepa no se puede mostrar todos los números de un double en caso de que sea tan largo.